# ionic admob banner ad closing tab menu

Tags: css, ionic-framework, admob, capacitor

ı have a problem for banner size when ı open app on large size phone ,banner closing tab menu https://prnt.sc/x7gsu6

```
private options: AdOptions = {
    adId: 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111',
    adSize: AdSize.SMART_BANNER,
    position: AdPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER,
    margin: 0,
    isTesting: true,
    // npa: true
  };
```

I give margin for tab menu

```
<ion-tab-bar slot="bottom" style="margin-bottom: 42px;">
```

capacitor plugin is  : https://github.com/capacitor-community/admob

I guess I'll use custom here but I don't understand how to use it

```
export declare enum AdSize {
    /**
     * Mobile Marketing Association (MMA)
     * banner ad size (320x50 density-independent pixels).
     */
    BANNER = "BANNER",
    /**
     * A dynamically sized banner that matches its parent's
     * width and expands/contracts its height to match the ad's
     * content after loading completes.
     */
    FLUID = "FLUID",
    /**
     * Interactive Advertising Bureau (IAB)
     * full banner ad size (468x60 density-independent pixels).
     */
    FULL_BANNER = "FULL_BANNER",
    /**
     * Large banner ad size (320x100 density-independent pixels).
     */
    LARGE_BANNER = "LARGE_BANNER",
    /**
     * Interactive Advertising Bureau (IAB)
     * leaderboard ad size (728x90 density-independent pixels).
     */
    LEADERBOARD = "LEADERBOARD",
    /**
     * Interactive Advertising Bureau (IAB)
     * medium rectangle ad size (300x250 density-independent pixels).
     */
    MEDIUM_RECTANGLE = "MEDIUM_RECTANGLE",
    /**
     * A dynamically sized banner that is full-width and auto-height.
     */
    SMART_BANNER = "SMART_BANNER",
    /**
     * To define a custom banner size, set your desired AdSize
     */
    CUSTOM = "CUSTOM"
}
```

Comment: _A dynamically sized banner that matches its parent's width and expands/contracts its height to match the ad's content after loading completes._

What ```FLUID``` gives you?

Comment: Thank you for your interest @ShinichiKudo FLUID result = <https://prnt.sc/x83jqh>